# SQL SERVER 2008 tree query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, hierarchical-data

I have a table called Module.
The table structure some things like:

```
ModuleID     ModuleName        ParentID

   1            System Manage       0
   2            Database Manage     1
   3            Area Manage         1
   4            Basic Setting       0
```

I would like to get the results below by a sql statement.

```
   ModuleID       ModuleName        ParentMoudle
     1               System Manage      0
     2               Database Manage    System Manage
     3               Area Manage        System Manage 
     4               Basic Setting      0
```

I am a  sql newbie .Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parent child relationship can be achived by LEFT OUTER JOIN and querying same table.

```
      select m.moduleid,m.modulename,COALESCE(p.modulename,0) from table as m
      left outer join table as p on m.moduleid = p.module.id
```

Comment: Note that this will only work if your hierarchy is only ever one level deep. If there are an undetermined number of levels, you'll have to resort to a CTE or the new HierarchyID type.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
;WITH Tree AS
(
    SELECT *, CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(25)) AS ParentName
      FROM @TT
     WHERE ParentID IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Fam.*,Tree.ModuleName AS ParentName
      FROM @TT AS Fam
     INNER JOIN Tree
        ON Fam.ParentID = Tree.moduleID
)
SELECT * FROM Tree
```